# What is the pdf of $X,Y$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

We know that the common pdf of $X,Y$ is constant function, on the triangle $(0,0),(0,1),(2,0)$ (and out of this range the value of the function is zero).
What is $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$?

**My solution:**
The area of the triangle is 1, so the constant function is:
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\cases{1\;\;0<x<2,0<y<1\\0\;Else}\\ $$
$1=\frac{1}{\text{the area of the triangle}}=\frac11=1$
So:
$$f_X(x)=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dy=\int _{0}^{-\frac{x}{2}+1}1\,dy=-\frac{x}{2}+1\\f_Y(y)=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dx=\int _{0}^{2-2y}1\,dy=2-2y$$
I'm right?
Or I miss something?

Thank you!

Comment: I see about 3 mistakes. The first is that your expression for $F_{XY}$ is $1$ on a rectangle, not a triangle. The second and third are incorrect bounds for the integration.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you, about the first mistake: The area of the triangle is:$$\frac{2\cdot 1}{2}=1$$, right? Abuot the others, I'm fixing it right now...

Comment: It may help to draw the triangle and a few horizontal and vertical slices of it on a piece of graph paper.

Comment: The area of the triangle is indeed $1$.

Comment: @user2357112, so it should be 1 instead of the function at the first one? As I edited it...

Comment: No. Again, I recommend drawing the triangle and a few vertical lines through it on some paper. See where the lines intersect the triangle for different values of $x$.

Comment: @user2357112, What I got is: $-\frac{x}{2}+1$ at the the top first integral... but it's right?

Comment: @user2357112, I edit to show you what I meant...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$f_{X,Y}$ is prescribed by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto1$ if $\left(x,y\right)\in\triangle$
and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto0$ otherwise, where $\triangle$ denotes
the triangle.

Then $f_{X}\left(x\right)=\int f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dy=\int_{\triangle\left(x\right)}dy=\lambda\left(\triangle\left(x\right)\right)$
where $\triangle\left(x\right)=\left\{ y\mid\left(x,y\right)\in\triangle\right\} $
and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesguemeasure.

**Addendum**:

Here $\triangle:=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\left(0,2\right)\times\left(0,1\right)\mid x+2y<2\right\} $.
Note that that the lines $2y+x=2$, $x=0$ and $y=0$ are the 'borders'
of the triangle.

Then for $x\in\left(0,2\right)$ you have $\Delta\left(x\right)=\left\{ y\in\left(0,1\right)\mid y<1-\frac{1}{2}x\right\} =\left(0,1-\frac{1}{2}x\right)$.
Consequently for $x\in\left(0,2\right)$ we find $f_{X}(x)=\lambda\left(\left(0,1-\frac{1}{2}x\right)\right)=1-\frac{1}{2}x$.

If $x\notin\left(0,2\right)$ then $\Delta\left(x\right)=\emptyset$
leading to $f_{X}\left(x\right)=0$.

Likewise you can define $\Delta'\left(y\right)=\left\{ x\mid\left(x,y\right)\in\triangle\right\} =\left\{ x\in\left(0,2\right)\mid x<2-2y\right\} $
leading to $f_{Y}\left(y\right)=2-2y$ for $y\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ if $y\notin(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand the hint...:-( can you explain more please?

Comment: Where I'm wrong at my answer??

Comment: In your formula for $f_X$ on RHS the $y$ must be replaced by $x$.

Comment: You are really wrong when it comes to $f_Y$. It should be $\int_{0}^{2-2y}1dx=2-2y$

Comment: I still not understand how I apply it to the integrals...

Comment: But, it's an option, right? $\int_{0}^{2-2y}1dx=2-2y$ is one way, and I choose the other...

Comment: But then $f_X$ will be with numbers (The integral...)

Comment: Do you understand your own formula of $f_X$ uptil $\int_{0}^{-\frac{1}{2}x+1}1dy$? It is okay. But the outcome of this integral is $-\frac{1}{2}x+1$
(agrees with my answer) and not $-\frac{1}{2}y+1$.

Comment: Yes!! You right, thank you!! But then, where is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is in the formula for $f_Y$. It is not $\int_{0}^{2}1dy$ but $\int_{0}^{2-2y}1dx=2-2y$ (for $y\in\left(0,1\right)$).
So not $dy$ but $dx$ and not $2$ but $2-2y$.

Comment: Now it right? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Everything is okay now, except that you must mention also that $f_X(x)=0$ if $x\notin (0,2)$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ if $y\notin (0,1)$. Cheers, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$$f_{XY} = \frac{1}{area A} = 1$$

$$f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{1-\frac{x}{2}} dy$$

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{2(1-y)} dx$$

$$F_{XY} = \frac{(1+y)x}{2}, 0\leq x \leq 2; 0\leq y\leq 1$$

Comment: Thank you! But we know that this is constant function so how do you got: $\frac{(1+y)x}{2}$?

Comment: What the heck? Why are you talking about cumulative functions? Where did you get a cubic term?

Comment: @user2357112, please tell me - my answer above is right?

Comment: @Yoar: No, and making incremental changes until someone tells you it's right is unlikely to teach you much.

Comment: @user2357112: So, I don't understand where is my mistake... :-( Can you tell me more please? Where I'm wrong? The constant function is one, right?

Comment: @user2357112, I might be wrong with the letters - I edit the Q...

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Please pay attention that I edit the Q... I need to find f and not F...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake

Comment: OP: Do you think a *product* CDF is likely in this context?